# How to split a linestring by its Z dimension

Tags: postgis, linestring

I have a `tracks` table with a `geom` column of type `geometry(LineStringZM,4326)`. I now need to find out how much time a user has spent at a given elevation range. For this I'm gonna create a materialized view. This is how far I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT r.id AS user_id,
    numrange(
        CASE WHEN r.min = -500 THEN -430 ELSE r.min END,
        CASE WHEN r.max = 9000 THEN 8849 ELSE r.max END,
        CASE WHEN r.max = 9000 THEN '()' ELSE '(]' END
    ) AS elevation
FROM (
    SELECT u.id,
        generate_series(-500, 8500, 500) AS min,
        generate_series(0, 9000, 500)    AS max
    FROM users u
) r
LEFT JOIN tracks t ON r.id = t.user_id
```

This gives me something like this:

```
user_id  elevation
1        (-430,0]
1        (0,500]
1        (500,1000]
1        (1000,1500]
1        (1500,2000]
1        (2000,2500]
1        (2500,3000]
1        (3000,3500]
1        (3500,4000]
1        (4000,4500]
1        (4500,5000]
1        (5000,5500]
1        (5500,6000]
1        (6000,6500]
1        (6500,7000]
1        (7000,7500]
1        (7500,8000]
1        (8000,8500]
1        (8500,8849)
```

What I'm having trouble with is splitting the linestring into chunks by the Z dimension.
`ST_Split`, for example, only takes another geometry as argument and drops the M dimension. I guess a solution could be to create a function that dumps all the points of a line and divvies them up into new linestrings somehow, but that seems inefficient to me.

Comment: Hi. You can try using `ST_LocateBetweenElevations(geom,zmin,zmax)` which seems to filter the Linestrings as you wish. This returns MultiLinestringZM as a subset of the input LinestringZM, keeping only the geometries in the relevant Z values. You would then need to handle the buckets and also sum the "M(endpoint) - M(startpoint)" for each item in each multilinestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for you.

Let's say your `tracks` table has a `userid` identifier and a `pathm` geometry of type LinestringZM. Z in meters or whatever, M in seconds or whatever.

Each userid might have multiple tracks (multiple lines in the table)

[image]

The main logic is to do the following, starting from the core process:

- `ST_LocateBetweenElevations(pathm,l.floor_alt_min,l.floor_alt_min+499)` to create MultilinestringZM with segments in the relevant altitude range (bucket width is `5OO` here thus the 499)
- `ST_Dump` the above to have multiple lines for each component of the MultilinestringZM
- `sum(st_m(st_endpoint((g.gdump).geom))-st_m(st_startpoint((g.gdump).geom)))) as duration` over the above : this sums the unitary duration of each sub-segment within a given altitude range

Now, what you also need is a table with all altitude buckets and userids. Let's generate the list of unique userid,altitude_buckets, that we use as a starting point to then apply the PostGIS related processes:

```
SELECT generate_series(0, 3000, 500) AS floor_alt_min) a cross join (select distinct userid from data.tracks
```

| UserId | Altitude_bucket |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 0 |
| 12345 | 500 |
| 12345 | 1000 |
| 12345 | 1500 |
| 12345 | 2000 |
| 12345 | 2500 |
| 12345 | 3000 |
| 77777 | 0 |
| 77777 | 500 |
| ... | ... |

Assemble everything together, cascading the temporary tables, aggregation and sorting. It should do the job to define your Materialized View:

```
select 
   l.userid,
   l.floor_alt_min,
   (select round(sum(st_m(st_endpoint((g.gdump).geom))-st_m(st_startpoint((g.gdump).geom)))) as duration from (select st_dump(ST_LocateBetweenElevations(pathm,l.floor_alt_min,l.floor_alt_min+499)) as gdump
   from data.tracks where userid=l.userid) g )
   from 
      (select distinct b.userid, a.floor_alt_min from 
         (SELECT generate_series(0, 3000, 500) AS floor_alt_min) a cross join
         (select distinct userid from data.tracks  limit 10) b order by b.userid asc, a.floor_alt_min asc) l
```

Here are the results for the altitude profiles of user `12345`, `98765` and `77777`:

Altitude(m) over time(s) taken from the sample LinestringZM, for each of the three `userid`:

[image]
`77777` has 2 similar tracks => double the time for this profile

| UserId | Altitude_bucket | Time spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 0 | 30.0 |
| 12345 | 500 | 30.0 |
| 12345 | 1000 | 30.0 |
| 12345 | 1500 | 30.0 |
| 12345 | 2000 | 60.0 |
| 12345 | 2500 | 60.0 |
| 12345 | 3000 |  |
| 77777 | 0 |  |
| 77777 | 500 |  |
| 77777 | 1000 | 480.0 |
| 77777 | 1500 |  |
| 77777 | 2000 |  |
| 77777 | 2500 |  |
| 77777 | 3000 |  |
| 98765 | 0 | 75.0 |
| 98765 | 500 | 15.0 |
| 98765 | 1000 | 15.0 |
| 98765 | 1500 | 15.0 |
| 98765 | 2000 | 120.0 |
| 98765 | 2500 |  |
| 98765 | 3000 |  |

It even interpolates over multiple ranges when one or several are skipped with no actual Point in the altitude range (which should not happen in your case I assume). Should be easy to add cumulated distance, average speed in each bucket as well

Comment: I searched quite a bit in the docs and on Google, but didn’t come across that function. Cheers for that! Will try it out after the holidays!

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to get back to this. Works great! Thanks!

Comment: One must say you were not in a hurry!